Laravel HTTP client: real multipart sample
Unfortunately, multipart sample in Laravel doc (here) contains only sample with one field (attached file) - Http::attach('file', $file_content).
It's not from real world - multipart request in most cases contains more than one field.
How to create multipart request by HTTP client with multiple fields where equivalent values provided by array?

Try this.
$result = Http::attach('attachment', file_get_contents($image), 'image.jpg', ['Content-Type' => 'image/jpg'])
          ->post('target-url', [
               'key1'=>$val1,  //pass post-data in array-format
               'key2'=>$val2
                ......
              ]);

By default, data will be sent using the application/json content-type.
Also fourth parameter of attach() is optional.
